# Motion in a magnetic field combined with a viscous medium

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

In a homogeneous, non magnetic, highly insulating and viscous medium, a moving particle experiences a viscous drag given by the law $\vec f=-b\vec v$. Here $b$ is a positive constant. A particle having charge $q$ is projected with an unknown velocity from a point in the medium. It almost stops after travelling a distance of $10m$ in a straight line. Now a uniform magnetic field is established in the region and the same particle is again launched with the same velocity perpendicular to magnetic field.

In the presence of above magnetic field, if the particle almost stops at a point $6m$ from the point of projection, then find the magnitude of magnetic field in terms of $q$ and $b$.

I was able to find an equation using the first case (absence of magnetic field).
$$10 = \frac{mv_{0}}{b}$$ where $m$ and $v_{0}$ are the mass and velocity of the projected charge.

How to proceed further? Need some hints.

Comment: What can't you just take $\vec F_{m}=q\vec v\times \vec B$ and just add the viscous drag?

Answer (score -1):

r=mv/qB

6=mv/qB

but; mv=10b

therefore;
6=10b/qB

rearranging;
B=5b/3q